# How do I make my script into a package to store in my GitHub?

Tags: python, git, pip

I have a one-file script that I use in several of my projects. For deployment purposes I wanted to make in into a nice package, and just put `git+https://github.com/me/my_repo` in `requirements.txt`. I downloaded example package from [here](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject), changed setup.py to include info about my package, and thought that was it. For some reason it doesn't work, and when I try to install it from git, all I get is some variation on this:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/tokenize.py", line 454, in open
    buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-1311r3r_-build/setup.py'
```

However, when I download the whole repo as a zip, it installs just fine. It also works in development mode on my computer. What am I doing wrong?

Current state if the repo: https://github.com/AFakeman/redis-map

Comment: Is `setup.py` located at the root of your Git repository?

Comment: @jwodder yes, it is.

Comment: I don't think we can provide any help unless you show us the repository (and possibly also the `requirements.txt` file).